# How to recognize and match patterns in audio segments of 2 or more short audio files using Python?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, audio-analysis

I'm working on a prototype, where I'm trying to find and match patterns between 2 audio files. As a naive example, let's assume we have two 5secs audio files which has my recordings as follows:
1. "I love dogs."
2. "Dogs are amazing!"

Here, I want to analyze and recognize certain features so that I can conclude that the common words between the 2 audio files is the word 'Dog'. Please note that the content is NOT important. Else I could've converted it to text and matched it. I want to analyse the common feature patterns. I've basic understanding of audio features such as mfcc, chromagrams, etc. but what and how to use in this context?

Comment: you need a Similarity Metric. You can try something simple like cosine distance on an analysis window of MFCC or chromagrams

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And, yes. I already implemented it with Euclidean distance metric between mfcc, spectral centroid, etc. and compared the features using cross_similarity module of librosa.